# Вывод случайного числа в диапазоне

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, я хоть в правильно направлении ? Задание, даны размеры (рост) (Маленькие - (60-100), (Средние - (101-140 см), (Большие - (141-200)).

Сделать метод, где за аргумент берутся самый низкий рост и самый большой, и генерируется случайное целое число в данном промежутке. Использовать для генерирования и округления числа класса Math методы ( Но нельзя использовать Random ). Если я конечно правильно понял, то нельзя использовать Math.Random().

```
import java.util.Random;

public class A5 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Random random = new Random();
        int num = 60 + random.nextInt (201 - 60);

        System.out.println(num);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Точно объяснить задание сможет только тот, кто его дал.

Answer (score 2):

Без класса `Random` можно так:

```
static long nextRandom(long min, long max) {
    return min + System.nanoTime() % (max - min + 1);
}
```